# Accessing the underlying array of a Memory<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, sonarqube, buffer, filestream

In my application I need to iterate over the contents of a file to make hashes of fixed-size chunks of the file. The end goal is to implement Amazon Glacier's Tree Hash algorithm, I almost verbatim copied the code from their documentation.

The problem happens when I run the following code through SonarQube though:

```cs
    byte[] buff = new byte[Mio];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buff, 0, Mio)) > 0) {
        // Process the bytes read
    }
```

I have a Roslyn issue on the line with the `while` loop. The issue is "Change the 'ReadAsync' method call to use the 'Stream.ReadAsync(Memory, CancellationToken)' overload". According to the description, it is because methods using the Memory class are more efficient than those using basic arrays.

That may be true when the class can used from end to end. The thing is, I need to feed the data to the `ComputeHash` method of a `HashAlgorithm`, and they don't have any override accepting a `Memory`. This means I must use the `ToArray` method of the `Memory`, which makes a *copy* of the data. This doesn't sound very efficient to me.

I know it is possible to create a `Memory` instance by passing an existing array to its constructor, like this:

```cs
    byte[] buff = new byte[Mio];
    Memory<byte> memory = new Memory<byte>(buff);
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(memory)) > 0) {
        // Use `buff` to access the bytes
    }
```

However the documentation is unclear whether the array passed to the constructor is actually used as the underlying storage for the `Memory` instance.

Thus, here are my questions:

- How can I directly feed the data from a `Memory` to a `HashAlgorithm` instance? I'm talking about *any* instance of a class that derives from `HashAlgorithm`, not specifically the SHA256 algorithm. My implementation is not restricted to SHA256 unlike the Glacier one.
- Is the data stored in the `Memory` instance also accesible in the array used to create it?
- Is there another way to access the data stored in the `Memory` instance as an array, **without copy**?
- Failing that, how can I silence an external issue in SonarQube (Roslyn warning in this case)? I don't have the dropdown to change its status like normal Sonar issues.

***EDIT*** Adding additional info on how the code works:
It's the first part of [AWS's example of computing a Glacier Tree Hash](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html), the part that computes the first hashes of 1Mio blocks from the file.

These are the contents of the `while` loop above:

```cs
// Constructor of the class
// The class implements IDisposable to properly dispose of the Algorithm field
// Constructor is called like this
// `using TreeHash treeHash = new TreeHash(System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512.Create());`
public TreeHash(HashAlgorithm algo) {
    this.Algorithm = algo;
}


// Chunk hash generation loop
// first part of the tree hash algorithm
    byte[][] chunkHashes = new byte[numChunks][];

    byte[] buff = new byte[Mio];
    int bytesRead;
    int idx = 0;

    while ((bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buff, 0, Mio)) > 0) {
        chunkHashes[idx++] = this.ComputeHash(buff, bytesRead);
    }


// Quick wrapper around the hash algorithm
// Also used by the second part of the tree hash computation
private byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] data, int count) => this.Algorithm.ComputeHash(data, 0, count);
```

I use the unprefixed versions of the hash algorithms by default but I can probably switch to the managed versions. And if needed the method can become non-`async`.

Comment: `TryComputeHash`/`TryHashData` both accept a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` You can pass it the `Span` property of the `Memory<byte>` (with any needed `Slice`'ing) and it will not make any copies but rather operate on the original array (or subsection of). You'll need to restructure a little bit in order to make use of the Try-pattern. What would really help your question is an example of how you are using `HashAlgorithm`, especially with respect to the current buffer/how it fits into your existing code. This way we can provide an actual answer

Comment: Also a clarification is that `TryHashData` is a `static` method on the various `HashAlgorithm` classes that use **unmanaged implementations**. Ie the classes that **don't** end in `Managed`. You've not mentioned which you are using, but I'd suggest using the `xxxManaged` versions if you aren't already. The instance method `TryComputeHash` is available on both the managed and unmanaged variants.

Comment: You've updated your question. But you've still not provided enough info. Please show the declaration of the `Algorithm` field/property so we can see the declared/static type of it. An example of how you initialize it may be helpful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. It makes use of the `MemoryPool<byte>` to get an `IMemoryOwner<byte>` that we can use to retrieve our scratch buffer. We need a `Memory<byte>` to pass to the `ReadAsync` call, so we pass the [`Memory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.imemoryowner-1.memory?view=net-5.0) property of the `IMemoryOwner<byte>`.

We then restructure the code to make use of the [`HashAlgorithm.TryComputeHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.trycomputehash?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithm_TryComputeHash_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_Span_System_Byte__System_Int32__) method which accepts a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` as the source and a `Span<byte>` as the destination. We *do* allocate a new array (rather than using the `ArrayPool`) since you are keeping/storing the arrays.

```cs
byte[][] chunkHashes = new byte[numChunks][]; 

using var memory = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(Mio);

int bytesRead;
int idx = 0; 

while ((bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(memory.Memory, CancellationToken.None)) > 0) 
{ 
   var tempBuff = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling(this.Algorithm.HashSize/8.0)];
   if (this.Algorithm.TryComputeHash(memory.Memory.Span[..bytesRead] /*1*/, tempBuff, out var hashWritten)) 
   {
      chunkHashes[idx++] = hashWritten == tempBuff.Length ? tempBuff : tempBuff[..hashWritten] /*2*/;
   } 
   else
      throw new Exception("buffer not big enough");
}
```

For the source, we pass the [`Span`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1.span?view=net-5.0) property of the `Memory<bytes>` buffer, which is again retrieved from the `IMemoryOwner<byte>.Memory` property. We slice it to the appropriate length based on the number of bytes read. The `Span<byte>` that we pass as the destination must be *at least* the size of the algorithm's [`HashSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.hashsize?view=net-5.0) property, which is the number of **bits** (*not* bytes) required for the hash. Since it's possible (though I believe unlikely) for an implementation to use a size that is *not* a multiple of 8 we *ceiling* the division to round up if necessary. We don't need to call `AsSpan` since there's an implicit conversion from `T[]`.

I believe* that the final number of bytes written will always be the same length as the `HashSize`. If/when it is, we simply make use of the original array. Otherwise we need to slice it to the correct length based on the number of hash bytes written.

In the event the buffer is not large enough, `TryComputeHash` returns `false` and we throw an exception. I'm fairly positive that this won't happen to us since we are explicitly calculating the size based on the `HashSize`, but we handle the case anyways as best practice.

I've passed `CancellationToken.None`, but you can supply your own token. I'm also using `Range` syntax instead of explicitly calling `Slice`. If that's unavailable to you or you simply don't like how it looks, you can can be explicit about it:

```cs
/*1*/ memory.Memory.Span.Slice(0, bytesRead)
/*2*/ tempBuff.AsSpan(0, hashWritten).ToArray()
```

Some *possible* assumptions we can make:

- assume `HashSize` is always multiple of 8
- assume `HashSize` is always equal to the number of bytes written and don't slice the final array
- assume that we're always providing a large enough buffer (which, per above would be the exact size needed) and remove the `if` and the `Exception`

```cs
while ((bytesRead = await inputStream.ReadAsync(memory.Memory, CancellationToken.None)) > 0)
{
   var tempBuff = new byte[this.Algorithm.HashSize/8];
   _ = this.Algorithm.TryComputeHash(memory.Memory.Span[..bytesRead], tempBuff, out _);
   chunkHashes[idx++] = tempBuff;
}
```

* Unfortunately I cannot say with 100% certainty that these are valid assumptions to make. Most of the implementations I've viewed the source code of have a `Debug.Assert` verifying the buffer size and bytes written are the same so I do think they are *reasonable*. That said, I think I would personally stick with the more verbose option.

You'll also note that I've removed your `ComputeHash` function. That's not to say you still can't use it, but I leave converting it to this `Try`-based `Memory<>` pattern as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I've fixed the syntax errors and have made the code `async` friendly (can't have local variables of `Span`/`ref structs`)

Comment: In the end I used a variation of the code snippets you provided, with `TryCompputeHash` and `memory.Span`. It works as intended. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nathan.EilishaShiraini no problem. I would make sure that you use the MemoryPool rather than creating a new Memory object yourself... Particularly since you appear to be concerned with additional, unnecessary allocations.